# How to restrict user acces to see/modify objects created by other users with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a hobby project with Django to store my ideas seperated by idea groups as the following:

```
class Idea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    in_process = models.BooleanField()
    is_done = models.BooleanField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
```

Is there any way to restrict the currently logged in user from being able to see or modify ideas and idea groups created by other users using generic class based views?

```
class GroupDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = Group
    pk_url_kwarg = "id"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ideas:list')
```

...and a url for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/delete', views.GroupDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

I'm using Django 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing a custom [mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-mixins) where you'd inherit the `LoginRequiredMixin` and then add your own logic verifying that the currently logged in user (which you can retreive from `request.user`) is the one who actually created the `Group` object.

Simple example would look something like this:

```
# mixins.py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound, HttpResponseRedirect


class YourCustomMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        can_access = ... logic to check if user can access Group ...

        disp = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(disp, HttpResponseRedirect) and not can_access:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
        return disp
```

Once you have a value for the `can_access` flag, you call the `LoginRequiredMixin`'s `dispatch` method and check if the result of that call is a redirect (to the login page) and check against the `can_access` flag, and then either return `HttpResponseNotFound()` or the original `disp` result.

Of course, you could also return `HttpResponseForbidden()` instead of `HttpResponseNotFound()`.

You can then use it in your views, e.g.:

```
from your_app.mixins import YourCustomMixin


class GroupDelete(YourCustomMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    ...
```